# Changes in $q service when migrating from Angular 1.2.18 to 1.4x

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm migrating angular version 1.2.4 to 1.4x.But I'm facing issues in $q service.
Below is my code:

in version 1.2x

```
var deferred=$q.defer();
```

where  `deferred.promise` contained the following function objects:
`catch`,`finally` and `then`
in version 1.4x this has changed to `$$state`
If anyone faced the similar issue.Please share your thoughts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a performance improvement made in version 1.3.0-beta.18.

The [commit responsible](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/23bc92b17df882a907fb326320f0622717fefe7b) has the following description:

> **perf($q): move Deferred and Promise methods to prototypes**
>   
> NOTE: Deferred doesn't get all the advantages of moving methods to the prototype,
>   since the constructor binds instance methods to "this" to support unbounded execution.
>   Closes #8300

This was to improve performance, since all instances of a class share the same prototype, whereas if you have them as properties of each instance, the browser has to allocate memory for the functions for each instance, not just once.

Answer (score 0):

I just check the `deferred` property and it still has the three functions `catch`, `finally` and `then`. `state` is a property. When i check the object hierarchy these methods seem to be defined on the prototype now.